# how to start and stop flink scala-shell in Apache flink

Tags: apache-flink, scala-shell

how to start and stop flink scala-shell in apache flink

I have started flink scala shell using the command /bin/start-scala-shell.sh local. But dont know how to stop ?

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-c (SIGINT) or ctrl-d (EOF) will exit the scala shell on mac and linux systems. Not sure about Windows.